# Android Facebook SDK shares text without link and image

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.1

```
 shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentDescription(description)
                            .build();

         shareDialog.show(linkContent);
 }
```

I want to post only text content on Facebook wall using Facebook SDK. How can I do it. please help

and I have used this following code

```
private fun postToFacebook() {

    mFacebook?.dialog(this,"feed" ,object :Facebook.DialogListener{

        override fun onComplete(values: Bundle?) {
          showToast("success")
        }

        override fun onFacebookError(e: FacebookError?) {
            showToast("error")
        }

        override fun onError(e: DialogError?) {
            showToast("error")
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            showToast("canceled")
        }

    })
}
```

This shows an error message for me but this code is working for a Youtube video.  error getting is herf or media required  error

[this following link they are doing what i needed i think they using old sdk is in eclips](https://us12.proxysite.com/process.php?d=LHG%2FLasardQkccZaSM0x%2BGUbddnsevvad%2BrYOVE%2BOKpXKgIBRhmT&b=9)

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: unable to post only text in feed i mean i need only text to be shared in wall ,

Comment: show screenshot.

Comment: i can't share text only error message is  "the parameter  "heref" or "media" is required "

Comment: no thing  to share in screen shot

Answer (score 0):

It's limitation of Android SDK due to Platform Policy. You can get more information here ([Sharing on Android - Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)), but in a few words - you cannot share predefined text via Facebook Share Widget:

> Use of the Android share sheet is subject to Facebook Platform Policy, including section 2.3 which states that apps may not pre-fill in the context of the share sheet. This means apps may not pre-fill the share sheet's initialText field with content that wasn't entered by the user of the app.

Comment: no need of share a predefined  text, i need a share widget in which we can type text  to share no need to attach link or image, any one did this prior?  i seen a youtube video  in which  they used the code what i used,  facebook stopped support for share text only? idk

Comment: https://us12.proxysite.com/process.php?d=LHG%2FLasardQkccZaSM0x%2BGUbddnsevvad%2BrYOVE%2BOKpXKgIBRhmT&b=9

Comment: shared  link of example what i needed